# Confusion about time scope of 日をもって

Tags: time

I have a sentence in the form 10月10日をもって辞めたい, for example。
Does this をもって mean "before", or "after".
Am I free on 10日 (i.e. work till 9日23:59). Or I still have to work on 10日, and get free on 11日?

Kind of classic time uncertainty in Japanese, but this use of をもって is new to me. I hope it has some certain meaning.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/72241/9831 `Time: 「10月31日を以てSEを辞めます。」 = "I shall leave SE as of October 31."`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is そんでもって?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/72063/what-is-%e3%81%9d%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%82%82%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6)

Comment: it neither explains the time scope, neither reading is explained there, making 以 disappear in the search for をもって.Meanwhile, でもってis not even related to the topic

You can see the correct answer below, given by sbkgs4686

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The previous state continues until the time specified by 〜を以って / 〜を以て  (written in 漢字 so people are aware this is not 持つ). So:

> 10月10日をもって辞めさせていただきます。

would mean:

> I will work through October 10th, after which I quit.
>   I will be quiting as of October 11th.

In English, the similar expression "as of" takes a look at when the resultant state **starts**. In Japanese, 〜をもって takes a look at when the previous state **ends**. This is why I think 〜をもって can be so tough to get the hang of for native English speakers.

Comment: I am not native. So, since advanced literature is available only in English, I am often floating in complete void. Thank you for clarification 

Comment: @Asdf That's my case too, our hope is to reach a Japanese level good enough to start learning in Japanese entirely